# Get Data from stored procedure as Datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a method to retrieve data from a database using a stored procedure as a DataTable like:

```
public DataTable GetTableBySQL(string sql) 
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), this.dbconn) 
    {
        CommandTimeout = 0,
        CommandType = CommandType.Text
    };

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Table1") 
    {
        Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    };

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    try 
    {
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        da.Fill(tbl);
    } 
    catch (SqlException e) 
    {
        this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetTableBySQL", sql.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
    }

    return tbl;
}
```

Now I call the stored procedure like this:

```
var empList = db.GetTableBySQL("$exec getMySP");
```

But when I execute, it just don't return any columns.

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main problems here (other smaller ones, but three that are important):

1. The `$exec` part of the SQL doesn't mean anything. Maybe you just want `exec`.
2. When the bad SQL fails, the error is hidden from the program, so you don't really know what happened.
3. The method signature doesn't support query parameters, and therefore will force you to write horribly insecure code that *will* result in someone hacking your application. Probably sooner rather than later. This is **really bad**, and you should not ignore it.

Try something more like this:

```
public DataTable GetTableBySQL(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters) 
{
    var result = new DataTable();

    //ADO.Net really does work better when you create a **NEW** connection
    //  object for most queries. Just share the connection string.
    //Also: "using" blocks are a better way to make sure the connection is closed.
    using (var dbconn = new SqlConnection(this.dbConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbconn))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        // A number of the properties set on the cmd and tbl variables just set the same value that was already there, didn't accomplish anything

        //It's hard to understate how important it is to use parameterized queries.
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        }

        try
        {
            da.Fill(result);
        } 
        catch (SqlException e) 
        {
            this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetTableBySQL", sql.ToString());
            //you may want to re-throw here, 
            // or even just remove the try/catch and let the error bubble up to calling code
        }
    }  
    return result;
}
```

Here it is again without all the extra explanatory comments, so you can see that doing it right is *less* code, rather than more:

```
public DataTable GetTableBySQL(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters) 
{
    var result = new DataTable();

    using (var dbconn = new SqlConnection(this.dbConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbconn))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        }

        da.Fill(result);
    }  
    return result;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var empList = db.GetTableBySQL("exec getMySP");
```

Comment: On c# we use `$` for interpolation, so you can use instead `string.Format`, I found issue. The correct way to call SP is `db.GetTableBySQL($"exec getMySP");`, also your answer is correct. Thanks

Comment: But there are no interpolation braces in that string, so you're asking the language to do extra work (look for braces) that won't change anything. Just remove the `$` from this string, and only use it when you need it.

Comment: Right. Thank you!